# Popular R packages for Quantitative Finance

Tags: r, quantitative

Which R packages (in this list or not) do you use in quant finance, why not an alternative, do you use it in production and if so, how?

There is a list of most of the R packages related to Finance by Dirk Eddelbuettel:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html

In addition:

- FinancialInstrument
- RTAQ
- blotter
- quantstrat

Comment: This should probably be closed for being overly broad and primarily opinion based. However, a list of popular packages (for R) and their uses can be a great asset for this as a Community Wiki. Would such a list also suit you @SMohan?

Answer (score 2):

I like Quantlib

http://quantlib.org/index.shtml

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/index.html

The QuantLib project is aimed at providing a comprehensive software framework for quantitative finance. QuantLib is a free/open-source library for modeling, trading, and risk management in real-life.

QuantLib is written in C++ with a clean object model, and is then exported to different languages such as C#, Objective Caml, Java, Perl, Python, GNU R, Ruby, and Scheme. The QuantLibAddin/QuantLibXL project uses ObjectHandler to export an object-oriented QuantLib interface to a variety of end-user platforms including Microsoft Excel and OpenOffice.org Calc. Bindings to other languages and porting to Gnumeric, Matlab/Octave, S-PLUS/R, Mathematica, COM/CORBA/SOAP architectures, FpML, are under consideration.